# Undefined symbols error under OSX 10.5.8

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc

I try to use CFLocaleCopyCurrent under OSX 10.5.8 but I get weird error:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    CFLocaleRef loc = CFLocaleCopyCurrent();
    return 0;
}

Undefined symbols:
"_CFLocaleCopyCurrent", referenced from: _main in ccn51XwH.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `/usr/bin/gcc -framework Foundation test.c`